Main Activity doesn't extend AppCompatActivity
once I open android studio and I found an error in main activty in some functions like "startActivity(intent) it gives an error: (cannot resolve method 'startActivity' in 'mainActivity')" and many others (my activity extend AppCompatActivity) and I run the app on my physical phone and also works fine without any runtime error. so I asked chatgpt and I tried build>clean project... build>rebuild project.... file>sync project with gradle files.... file>Invalidate caches but non of these works for me.once I make my activity extends Activity only so the project works fine but I can't use themes and action bar and what I understand from that is AppCompatActivity doesn't extend Activity also fragmentActivity (gradle and manifest and all activities works fine with no issues and all dependencies are okay)..... but when I created this project it was extend AppCompatActivity normally just like other projects.... so I think that there is a missing folder or its path is missing or someone moves this folder from its original path in the file explorer
actually I don't know how this error comes so I can't make the error again but what I  did is make a new project with empty activity but and I faced this error again... i make two activities and by Intent to pass between them
Intent intent = new Intend(MainActivity.this, newActivity.class);      startActivity(intent); so i have error on startActivity that says "can't resovle this methode 'startActivity' in 'mainActivity'" and in the manifest a red line under the activity name that says 'mainActivity must extend android.app.activity' and also in newActiivty
here is my manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.tbgroup">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TBGroup"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".newActivity" //here is the error
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" //here is the error
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

and here is the gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tbgroup"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

and here is the mainActivity
package com.example.tbgroup;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActiivty.class);
        startActivity(intent);  //here is the error
    }
}

newActivity
package com.example.tbgroup;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class newActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_activity);
    }
}

so any help to fix that would be appreciated!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
